# Access Modifiers and multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have two seperate project(Dll).

Project 1: contains abstract classes.

Project 2: specific concrete classes that extends abstract classes in Project 1.

I want my abstract classes to be accessible only in classes that is derived from. normally i will use "protected", but since they are not in the same assembly this can not be used.

What Access Modifiers should Project 1 classes use?

**Edit:** class definition EX

```
namespace all.Animals
{
    public abstract class Animal
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe i have misunderstood this, but when i try to use `protected`, I will get: `"Modifier is not valid for class XXX"`

Comment: what's your full class definition?

Comment: Use `internal` as @Darin Dimitrov pointed out.

Comment: @DovydasSopa That will not work. since project 2 in NOT in the same assembly therefore NOT internal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the abstract classes defined in Project1 assembly to be visible only to classes in Project2 assembly then make those classes `internal` and then set the [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) assembly level attribute on Project1.

Bear in mind though that the assemblies that have access to Project1 classes are baked into this Project1 assembly. So if tomorrow you decide that Project3 also needs to access those classes you will need to recompile Project1.

Comment: Maybe i have misunderstood, but why is it that i can't use `protected` which should be the ideal Modifier?

Comment: Because there's no such notion as a `protected` class in .NET. The protected keyword only has meaning for members. For classes you need to chose between `public` or `internal`. If you chose `internal` then combining it with the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute as suggested in my answer you will be able to restrict the assemblies that are allowed to access those abstract classes.